# How To Use Formula In Order To Find The Recommended Company In Excel

Tags: excel

I need to know whether these is a formula to find the selected company using excel.

For Example, I use the Min formula to find the lowest value between 3 selected company. But what I want is to auto select the company name with the lowest value.

Eg.

[image]

Any help is really much appreciated.

Comment: Use INDEX/MATCH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Excel365` you can use `XLOOKUP()` in this way.

```
=XLOOKUP(MIN(A2:C2),A2:C2,A1:C1)
```

You can also use `INDEX/MATCH` as @BigBen suggested.

```
=INDEX(A1:C1,,MATCH(MIN(A2:C2),A2:C2,0))
```

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thanks! I already tried using the index/match for Excel 2013. However, for xlookup function was not available. Anyhow, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Zazaf If it worked then please accept the answer (tick mark it).

Comment: Sir, what if i want to exclude the value 0 to find the selected company?

Comment: Not understand. Can you explain little more.